# How to send hashmap <Object,boolean> as a JSON to angular controller?

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest

I am quite new to AngularJS. I am trying to send a hashmap over to angular controller through a REST service. I am using JSONContentEncapsulator for the same. I am not sure about the syntax.
`JSONContentEncapsulator<HashMap> encapsulator = new JSONContentEncapsulator<HashMap>(sampleHashmap);`
The problem is my Hashmap is sent over to controller with the object converted in the string format.
Also when I try printing the key value pair on the screen using ng-repeat, it's blank.
but when I print it in my controller using forEach I am able to see the values.
Could anyone please help as to how I should achieve this so that I can retrieve the object and corresponding boolean value on the screen?

EDIT1: The json values returned by REST service in my controller look like below:
`{"EventValue(eventValueId=14, eventValueDescription=Deb Basic Neg Settle-intern plus   , valueClassId=ALTBASIC, resultType=CALC, creditdebitIndicator=DEBIT, sign=POSITIVE, custAccountType=INTERNAL_SETTLEMENT)":true,"EventValue(eventValueId=11, eventValueDescription=Cred Basic Neg Correction minus    , valueClassId=ALTBASIC, resultType=CORP, creditdebitIndicator=CREDIT, sign=NEGATIVE, custAccountType=NA)":true}`
Where EvenValue is the object which is used as key and there is corresponding  boolean value with it.

Comment: post the json value returned from the rest service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read online. It is not possible to send Map with Object as key in JSON format.
So instead I created two arraylists out of the map and sent those as a part of a single nested list.
It works fine.